# Golang template to format docker ps output as JSON

Tags: json, docker, go, go-templates

I am wondering if it is possible to add the additional formating required to make this output a valid JSON string.  To do so I need one character at the start, one on every line except the last, and then one final character.

I currently have this;

```
$ sudo docker ps --format "{ \"{{.ID}}\" : \"{{.Names}}\"}"
{ "85c4c597bef9" : "addon_a0d7b954_nodered"}
{ "ec3c55af0497" : "addon_a0d7b954_appdaemon"}
{ "63e3081fbe42" : "addon_a0d7b954_logviewer"}
```

I cannot work out how to use Go to just put out a single character at the start (or even if it is possible).

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/config/formatting/ ?

Comment: Can't see that it helps. the `{{ json .ID}}` simply converts that value to a valid JSON. It doesn't output a complete JSON string (i.e. an array of objects).

Comment: have you tried `{{json .}}` ?

Comment: Useful (in that for each container it outputs a valid JSON) but does not quite do what I was looking for as the answer does but this version gives all the info as a valid JSON String
`echo ] | (sudo docker ps --format "{{json .}}" | paste -sd',' && cat) | (echo [ && cat)`

Comment: after some fiddling, i think i found another suitable answer `docker ps -a --format "{{json .}}" | jq "{ID, Names}" | jq -s` i could not avoid calling jq twice, but that works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you specify a template, but that template is applied individually on each of your containers, and each template result is rendered in a new line. Your template does not apply to a list of items, but to individual items, and how the result is outputted (how the lines are joined) is not in your control.

But you may achieve what you want with linux commands.

This code demonstrates how your template is executed:

```
src := "{ \"{{.ID}}\" : \"{{.Names}}\"}"
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(src))

ps := []map[string]string{
    {"ID": "85c4c597bef9", "Names": "addon_a0d7b954_nodered"},
    {"ID": "ec3c55af0497", "Names": "addon_a0d7b954_appdaemon"},
    {"ID": "63e3081fbe42", "Names": "addon_a0d7b954_logviewer"},
}

for _, p := range ps {
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, p); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

This outputs what you have currently (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NNl3TcW0t4c)):

```
{ "85c4c597bef9" : "addon_a0d7b954_nodered"}
{ "ec3c55af0497" : "addon_a0d7b954_appdaemon"}
{ "63e3081fbe42" : "addon_a0d7b954_logviewer"}
```

You may use `paste` to join the lines with a comma like this:

```
docker ps --format "{ \"{{.ID}}\" : \"{{.Names}}\"}" |paste -sd','
```

One last thing: prepend a `[` and append a `]` so it becomes a valid JSON array.

To append something to a command's output, you may use

```
echo something | (command && cat)
```

To omit the newline caused by `echo`, you may use `echo -n`.

So your "wished" output is a series of appends: `]` to the output of `docker`, and that to the output of the single `[`.

So the solution in your case:

```
echo ] | (docker ps --format "{ \"{{.ID}}\" : \"{{.Names}}\"}" | paste -sd',' && cat) | (echo [ && cat)
```

This will output:

```
[
{ "85c4c597bef9" : "addon_a0d7b954_nodered"},{ "ec3c55af0497" : "addon_a0d7b954_appdaemon"},{ "63e3081fbe42" : "addon_a0d7b954_logviewer"}
]
```

Comment: Brilliant, many thanks.  I did use one of the earlier suggestions and use the son formatting rather than escaped double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

a go-ish solution might look like this, although i am not sure how it will behave with nested objects.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    dec := json.NewDecoder(os.Stdin)
    enc := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
    fmt.Println("[")
    d := map[string]interface{}{}
    var i int
    for {
        err := dec.Decode(&d)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            log.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        if i > 0 {
            fmt.Println(",")
        }
        enc.Encode(d)
        i++
    }
    fmt.Println("]")
}
```

then, `docker ps -a --format "{{json .}}" | jq "{ID, Names}" | go run gow/src/test/jsonl/main.go`

Answer (score 0):

jq helps.

To get the complete json for reference.

```
docker ps -a --format "{{json .}}" | jq -s
```

To get only the required columns in the output with tab separated version

```
docker ps -a --format "{{json .}}" | jq -r -c '[.ID, .State, .Names, .Image] | @tsv'
```